# regular expression for password in web2py

Tags: web2py, web2py-modules

I am using the auth module for the login process for my web2py application.I want to validate the password using regular expressions but couldn't find a way for it.How could we modify the access control to accept regex

Answer (score 2):

In a model file (likely in db.py), you should have the following line, which defines all the `Auth` tables, including `db.auth_user`:

```
auth.define_tables()
```

When the `db.auth_user` table is defined, the `requires` attribute of its `password` field is set to be a list containing a single `CRYPT` validator. If you would like to apply a regular expression validation, you can do so by inserting an `IS_MATCH` validator *before* the `CRYPT` validator in the `requires` attribute. To do this, anywhere *after* the above line, include the following:

```
password_is_match = IS_MATCH(r'your_regex', error_message='Your error message',
                             search=True)
db.auth_user.password.requires.insert(0, password_is_match)
```

Note, if you do not set `search=True`, the validator will prepend your regex with a "^".

Also, note that the reason for inserting the `IS_MATCH` validator before the `CRYPT` validator is that the `CRYPT` validator transforms the password by hashing it, so any validators applied *after* the `CRYPT` validator will receive the hashed password rather than the original.

Comment: where would I have the list of validators in web2py so that I could insert this line

Comment: if you haven't change anything this should be inside model db.py

Comment: Hopefully the edited answer clarifies things. Just use the code as shown in the answer -- you do not have to find any list of validators anywhere.